# inner join sin duplicados

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo un sistema en `php` en el cual tengo dos tablas en una guardo los registros y en otra las casillas en donde va cada registro, el resultado me queda de esta manera

```
-------- -------- --------------- 
CASILLA  SECCION  REPRESENTANTE 
-------- -------- --------------- 
B        1028     14
C1       1028     15
C2       1028
```

En representante se guarda el `id` del representante que registro pero cuando la consulta con el `inner join` me omite el que no tiene id, esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT 
    rc.apaterno,
    rc.amaterno,
    rc.nombre,
    encarte.seccion,
    encarte.casilla
FROM
    encarte
INNER JOIN rc ON encarte.id_representante = rc.id
OR encarte.id_representante IS NULL
```

y me trae estos datos

```
-------- -------- ------------ ------- --------
APATERNO AMATERNO NOMBRE       SECCION CASILLA
-------- -------- ------------ ------- -------
cedillo   moller  carlos       1028    B
marco     garcia  martinez     1028    C1
```

Comment: Si quieres que te traiga los registros asi el campo este null, debes usar LEFT JOIN en vez de INNER JOIN

Answer (score 3):

Cuando usas **INNER JOIN** SQL trae los resultados donde ambas partes tienen una relación, mientras que un LEFT O RIGTH JOIN prioriza el conjunto de resultados que se encuentran del lado indicado, izquierda o derecha, sin importar si el otro lado se intersecta. Para tu pregunta tu sentencia sería:

```
SELECT 
    rc.apaterno,
    rc.amaterno,
    rc.nombre,
    encarte.seccion,
    encarte.casilla
FROM
    encarte
LEFT JOIN rc ON encarte.id_representante = rc.id
```

Así prioriza a la tabla [encarte] y si la tabla [rc] por la union (encarte.id_representante = rc.id) no tiene nada, devolverá [null]. Devolviendote algo así:

```
NULL, NULL, NULL, 1028, B
```

Si quieres conocer mas al respecto o técnicamente, revisa este [enlace](https://www.genbetadev.com/bases-de-datos/explicacion-grafica-de-los-join-en-sql-y-sus-resultados). Otra cosa también investiga algo sobre alias para que mejores tu código. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Tu consulta quedaría así:

```
SELECT rc.apaterno, rc.amaterno, rc.nombre, encarte.seccion, encarte.casilla 
FROM encarte LEFT JOIN rc ON encarte.id_representante = rc.id
```